# How to fix nested menu which is working partially

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I am learning HTML and CSS. I am trying to make a webpage but the menu of the webpage is not working fully.

There is another menu in the main menu like the nested menu (I actually don't know what it is called). The first menu is working perfectly but the nested menu is not working. I want, if I click on the `Menu` option, which is indicated in the image, the second menu appears over the first menu.

The red mark on the image is the link to the second menu.

My menu will be like [Starbucks](https://www.starbucks.com/) menu which appears when the width is `768px`.

[image]

My Codes:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 83px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header .logo {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.header .logo img {
    width: 50px;
}

.toogle-menu {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 2rem;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.spinner {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.middle {
    opacity: 0;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.top {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.bottom {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -16px;
}

#menu:checked ~ .sidebarMenu, .nested-menu a #nested:checked ~ .menu-2 {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebarMenu, .menu-2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80vw;
    margin-top: 83px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(235, 227, 227);
    transform: translateX(80vw);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebarMenu ul, .menu-2 ul {
    padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
}

.sidebarMenu ul li, .menu-2 ul li {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sidebarMenu ul li a, .menu-2 ul li a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.nested-menu a label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nested-menu a input {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-list {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.btn {
    padding: 7px 16px !important;
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    color: #1E3932 !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.btn-black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hamburger Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./starbucks-logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
        <label for="menu" class="toogle-menu">
            <div class="spinner top"></div>
            <div class="spinner middle"></div>
            <div class="spinner bottom"></div>
        </label>
        
        <div class="sidebarMenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="nested-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="nested">
                        <label for="nested">Menu <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                <hr>
                <li class="btn-list">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Sign in</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-black">Join now</a>
                </li>
                <li class="location"><a href=""><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Find a store</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">All Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Previous Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Favorite Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why it is not working?

How can I fix the issue and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `.menu-2` with the next item after `<input type="checkbox" id="nested" />`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 83px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header .logo {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.header .logo img {
    width: 50px;
}

.toogle-menu {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 2rem;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.spinner {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.middle {
    opacity: 0;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.top {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#menu:checked ~ .toogle-menu > .spinner.bottom {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -16px;
}

#nested {
    display: none;
}

#menu:checked ~ .sidebarMenu,
.nested-menu #nested:checked ~ .menu-2 {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebarMenu,
.menu-2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80vw;
    margin-top: 83px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(235, 227, 227);
    transform: translateX(80vw);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebarMenu ul,
.menu-2 ul {
    padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
}

.sidebarMenu ul li,
.menu-2 ul li {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sidebarMenu ul li > *,
.menu-2 ul li a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nested-menu a label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nested-menu a input {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-list {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.btn {
    padding: 7px 16px !important;
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    color: #1e3932 !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.btn-black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Hamburger Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="./starbucks-logo.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
            <label for="menu" class="toogle-menu">
                <div class="spinner top"></div>
                <div class="spinner middle"></div>
                <div class="spinner bottom"></div>
            </label>

            <div class="sidebarMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nested-menu">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="nested" />
                        <label for="nested">Menu <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>

                        <div class="menu-2">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">All Orders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Previous Orders</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Favorite Products</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                    <hr />
                    <li class="btn-list">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Sign in</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-black">Join now</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="location">
                        <a href=""><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Find a store</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly I wanted this behavior. Thank you so much. You are a lifesaver.

Comment: @SatyajitRoy, glad to help.